# Not Deleting, error in trigger function?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sql-delete, procedure

I'm trying to create a trigger that once an employee (Table Employee) is deleted, the customer(Table Customer) who had that employee as SupportRep, gets assigned the former employee's "boss"(Known as ReportsTo). I created this trigger function, and when I try to delete an employee, the query is successfull but doesn't really delete anyone.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION REEMPLAZAR() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $CAMBIO$

BEGIN
    UPDATE "Customer"
    SET "SupportRepId" = old."ReportsTo"
    WHERE "SupportRepId" IS NULL;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$CAMBIO$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And this would be the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ac_supp BEFORE DELETE 
    ON "Employee" FOR EACH ROW 
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE REEMPLAZAR();
```

When I run:

```
 DELETE FROM public."Employee"
 WHERE "EmployeeId" = 9;
```

It supposedly executes succesfully but when I check the Employee table, the employee I tried to delete is still there, and there was no update on the Customers table whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you just doing this?

```
UPDATE "Customer"
    SET "SupportRepId" = old."ReportsTo"
    WHERE "SupportRepId" IS NULL;
```

I'm not sure the logic is correct to solve your problem, but this seems like a much simpler solution -- and doesn't require querying the table the trigger is defined on.

Comment: I updated my code, don't know if that's what you meant? Thanks anyway, you're right, it is a much simpler solution. Still having the same problem though :(